# JPA - How to apply observer pattern to entities?

Tags: java, jpa, observer-pattern

I've an entity of which I would like to apply the Observer pattern. In my UI I've a class that has to be notified by the entity when certain data of the entity has changed.

The problem is that the entity retrieved by finding it with the EntityManager is not the same instance on which I attached the observer and so the observer list (observerList) which is an instance variable of the entity is empty. The observer list hasn't to be persisted. It has the annotation @Transient.

In my (Vaadin-Web-)application I keep track of the enetities currently in use by the user, by storing the Ids of the entities in a so called appdata variable. When I need the Entity I use find() of the Entitymanager.

How to solve? Should I store the entity instead of the id and do a merge instead of a find?

Answer (score 0):

My question is more ore less answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582228/868879) post.

When merging the entity, just copy the transient variables into the merged entity. It would be nice if the JPA did this copy action for me.