# PostPersist setting the transeint field to null

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an entity that contain some transient fields that will be used after the persisting of this entity. The problem is that when the post persist is called these fields are turned into null.
Is this normal in jpa? If so, how I can allow those fields to remain not null?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You'll find the explanation in the accepted answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581665/jpa-transient-information-lost-on-create

Comment: you could use an implementation that doesn't null those fields. Think DataNucleus JPA doesn't IIRC

Comment: Without more information there is no way to tell what is causing the fields to be null.  No information is given other than mention of persist, and persist should not cause fields to be set to null in any JPA provider I've seen.  What are you doing exactly?

Comment: i am bounded to eclipse link @NeilStockton .

Comment: the explanation you mentioned is true for post persist but the same problem occur with pre persist @Chafik

Comment: @Chris read the link mentioned by chafik and you will understand the problem. which cannot be solved if i have to use eclipse link

Comment: So you are using merge?  Don't use merge, use persist instead then.  Without the code showing what you are doing, it's hard to help.