# Edit an entity without executing @PreUpdate method

Tags: java, jpa

In almost every Entity Classes within my application there is a Timestamp field to save the time, when the Entity has been changed by the user. For that behaviour I am using a simple method, annotated with `@PreUpdate` to set the value of this field to the current `java.util.Date`.

This basic functionality is excluded into some BasicEntity class, which I am extending for spefific implementation. So it basically looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BasicEntity {
    // ...
    @PreUpdate
    public void preupdate() {
        this.lastupdate = new java.util.Date();
    } 
}

@Entity
public class User extends BasicEntity {
    private java.util.Date lastlogin;
}
```

Now I have the requirement not only to save the time of the last update action, but also the time, when a User logs in into the system. So currently, wihtin my login method, I am setting the field for the last login to the current date and saving the current state of this User instance through the EntityManager. But then of course the field for the last update is also set because of my `@PreUpdate` method.

I do not want that to happen in this specific case! Somehow I want to be able to change the value of my `lastlogin` field without changing the value of the `lastupdate` field.

Do you have a suggestion how I could achieve this in this case? Because of lot of additional features provided by the `BasicEntity` I'd like to avoid going back from extending it.

---

Current attempt:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BasicEntity {
    // ...
    @PreUpdate
    public void preupdate() {
        this.lastupdate = new java.util.Date();
    } 
}

@Entity
public class User extends BasicEntity {
    @Transient
    protected volatile transient boolean login = false;

    @Override
    @PreUpdate
    public void preupdate() {            
        if (!login) {
            super.preupdate();
        }
        login = false;
    }
}
```

In my Login-method I am doing the following:

```
getUser().setLogin(true);    
userFacade.edit(getUser());
```

But now, when the preupdate() method of User is executed, the value of `login` is still `false`.

Comment: I'd make a new entity, `UserLogin`, with a many-to-one to your `User` entity, and insert values into it for logins instead.

Comment: Wouldn't this invoke some em.merge operation on the `User` anyway and thus callng the `@PreUpdate` method?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class BasicEntity {
        // ...
        @Transient
        protected volatile transient boolean updated = true;        

        @PreUpdate
        public void preupdate() {
          if(updated){
            this.lastupdate = new java.util.Date();
          }
        } 
    }

    @Entity
    public class User extends BasicEntity {
        private java.util.Date lastlogin;

    public void setLastLogin(Date lastlogin){
       this.lastlogin = lastlogin;
       this.updated = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess I will try to modify this approach in that way, that I am overridng my @PreUpdate method in User, but in general this sounds like a good idea!

Comment: The update field should be marked transient and volatile (both @Transient and transient).

Comment: @Panchitoboy Unfortunately the approach with having a transient field does not work here in general by design of the JPA specification ... but maybe you are interested in my current solution

Comment: Thank you, is usefull to know that type the behavior

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the approach with using a transient field does not work here by specification design. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582228/1803294)  as well for more details.

I ended up by using an ugly hack. This is my final solution:

Inside Login-method:

```
getUser().setLastlogin(DateUtil.LOGIN);                
userJpa.edit(getUser());
```

Entity class:

```
@Override
@PreUpdate
public void preupdate() {    
    if (lastlogin != null && !lastlogin.equals(DateUtil.LOGIN))  {            
        super.preupdate();
    }
    else {
        lastlogin = new java.util.Date();
    }
}
```

`LOGIN` is just a constant Date instance here, which I am using to decide whether I want to perform the PreUpdate method of the Superclass or not. Not really nice, but in Production use in works..