# Access non mapped properties in JPA LifecycleEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with non-mapped properties and a LifeCycleCallBback Listener. 
In PrePersist/PreUpdate callback the non-mapped property is null but before the save was triggered this property was set.

I tried to annotate it with @Transient but it doesn't work as well. I tried to staticly give the property to the listnener but it does not support heavy loading.

```
public abstract class AbstractA {
    private Object a;
    public void setA(Object a){
        this.a = a;
    }
    public Object getA(){
        return a;
    }
}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyListener.class)
public class B extends AbstractA {
    //...
}

public class BService {
    public B save(B b){
        b.setA(object); // Object is not null and object.getA returns the good value
        bRepository.saveAndFlush(b); // Triggers the prePersist Callback
    }
}

public class MyListener {
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(AbstractA a){
        a.getA(); // here a.a is null
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. In my code this works.Have a look at this project: https://github.com/simasch/entitylistener-with-non-managed-field

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I finally found this post and why the property is null. The fact that it was in an abstract parent class had nothing to do with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581665/jpa-transient-information-lost-on-create