# Transient field is lost when appending new OneToMany entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities which are linked via a OneToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bookcase")
public class BookCase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    @Getter @Setter private Long oldId;

    /*
    https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/
    */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookCase", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Bookshelf> bookShelves = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
    public Set<Bookshelf> getBookShelves() { return bookShelves; }
    public void setBookShelves(Set<Bookshelf> bookShelves) { this.bookShelves = bookShelves; }
}



@Entity
@Table(name="bookshelf")
public class Bookshelf {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bookshelf.class);
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    @Getter @Setter private Long oldId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookcase_id")
    private BookCase bookCase;

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }


    public BookCase getBookCase() { return bookCase; }

    public void setBookCase(BookCase bookCase) {
        this.bookCase = bookCase;
        bookCase.getBookShelves().add(this);
    }

    @Transient
    @Setter private OldIdListener oldIdListener;

    /*
    When the id is saved, listening DTOs can update their ids
    */
    @PostPersist
    public void triggerOldId() {
        log.info("Postpersist triggered for {}", id);
        if (oldIdListener != null) {
            oldIdListener.updateId(oldId, id);
        }
    }
}

public interface OldIdListener {
    void updateId(long oldId, long newId);
}
```

The following test fails:

```
@Test
public void testThatCascadingListenerIsTriggered() {

    var mock = mock(OldIdListener.class);
    var mock2 = mock(OldIdListener.class);
    var mock3 = mock(OldIdListener.class);

    var bookcase = new BookCase();

    var shelf1 = new Bookshelf();
    shelf1.setOldId(-5L);
    shelf1.setBookCase(bookcase);
    shelf1.setOldIdListener(mock);

    var shelf2 = new Bookshelf();
    shelf2.setOldId(-6L);
    shelf2.setBookCase(bookcase);
    shelf2.setOldIdListener(mock2);

    var saved = bookCaseRepository.save(bookcase);

    verify(mock).updateId(eq(-5L), anyLong());
    verify(mock2).updateId(eq(-6L), anyLong());


    var savedBookCase = bookCaseRepository.findById(saved.getId()).get();

    assertThat(savedBookCase.getBookShelves()).hasSize(2);


    var shelf3 = new Bookshelf();
    shelf3.setOldId(-10L);
    shelf3.setBookCase(savedBookCase);
    shelf3.setOldIdListener(mock3);

    savedBookCase.getBookShelves().add(shelf3);
    bookCaseRepository.save(savedBookCase);
    verify(mock3).updateId(eq(-10L), anyLong());
}
```

mock3 is never called.
When debugging the code, I can see that the transient fields `oldId` and `oldIdListener` are set to null when the `@PostPersist` method is called on object shelf3, not on shelf1 and 2.

I think this is because I am modifying the Set object; but the object is correctly persisted, it just loses all transient fields. This does not happen when the entire tree is persisted for the first time.

Is this the wrong way to insert a new element to a OneToMany set or where is the error here?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Once you realize the second call to `bookRepository.save(bookCase)` results in `em.merge()`, rather than `em.persist()`, the explanation for the behaviour you're seeing is basically the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581665/jpa-transient-information-lost-on-create)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. This helped me much. I also found this article in the meantime: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/

Answer (score 1):

The field which annotation with @Transient will not persist to the database, so if you want it to persist, you must remove @Transient.